# Does pywinauto use the Windows Automation API?

Tags: python, pywinauto

I was reading the docs but could not figure out whether pywinauto uses the [Windows Automation API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/windows-automation-api-portal) or not. If so, can it do everything the Automation API can or do I need to use .net to harness the full capabilities of the API?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pywinauto can use Windows Automation API (a.k.a. UI Automation API) at your choice. It's taken from native `UIAutomationCore.dll` using native COM interfaces (analogue of UIAComWrapper for .NET to eliminate .NET specific bugs).

This is all described in the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html). All you need is using `Application(backend="uia")`. Default backend is still "win32" which will be changed in the next major release.